# How do I propagate the error in a determinant in python

Tags: python, linear-algebra, determinants

I have a matrix in which each component has an associated error. I need to calculate the determinant of the matrix and the error on that value, obtained by error propagation. I found this "uncertainties" package online but I can't seem to make it work with determinants. Here is what I tried so far:

```
from uncertainties import unumpy
import numpy as np
a = unumpy.uarray([1,1,1],[0,0,0])
b = unumpy.uarray([4,7,9],[0.1,0.1,0.1])
c = unumpy.uarray([4.95,8.05,10],[0.1,0.1,0.1])
m = np.array([a,b,c])
np.linalg.det(m)
```

I am getting this error: `TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc det`. I guess there is an actual built in function that would allow me to get the determinant, other than `np.linalg.det`, but I can't find it. Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: You need a square matrix,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant still trying to see what shape your matrix is and cannot quite work it out as I don't use unumpy.

Comment: @jwal the matrix I have is 3x3, it is a square matrix

Comment: numpy reports it as 'O' (Python) objects, which linalg will throw on. Min and max are reported as not numeric by numpy.

Comment: @jwal I am not sure what you mean. I just need a way to calculate error propagation.

Comment: as far as numpy is concerned your array does not have numbers in it. Hmm, I've a vaguely non-trivial idea.

Comment: @jwal but if I call np.mean(b) for example, I get the right answer. Why does it not work with determinants, too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232469/discussion-between-jwal-and-billket).